# Installshield: Targeting both 32bit and 64bit systems at the same package

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

I want to create an installation that will be launched on 32 or 64 bit systems. I need to deploy VS2012 merge modules for both platforms as well. But to do this the "Template Summary" should be set correctly, and my problem is that I can't do it.

When setting the template summary to: `Intel;1033`, I get the following error:

```
error -5008: intel64 or amd64 must be specified in the template of the summary
```

And when setting to: `Intel64;1033`, so the installation won't run on 32-bit systems.

And of course setting to `Intel;Intel64;1033` is not allowed.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Installer doesn't officially support hybrid x86/x64 installers.  There are some tricks but they won't work if you try to use the merge modules that you mention.

If it was me, I'd look at using the Visual Studio C++ redists (you didn't call them this, but I'm assuming this is what you meant ) using setup prerequisites.   This will allow your setup.exe to run and preinstall the x86 and/or x64 runtimes using their own x86/x64 installation packages.   Then your main installer will run.

At this point it's very likely your main installer doesn't need to be hybrid x86 and x64.  If you are the typical AnyCPU compiled .NET application it'll probably just work.   You might have some native DLL's that are bit sensitive and you'll have to use the VersionNT64 property to decide which one to install.

It's hard to give 100% specific advice without seeing your application.

Comment: Great! Installing the runtimes this way really solves my problem and might help others who face this situation. It even has a /quiet option to hide the installation GUI.